# Why is it causing run-time error even though we are passing it by pointer?

Tags: c

Can someone explain why it is resulting in a run-time error and what should I add to stop the runtime error? I thought it would work as array1 is an array of 10 pointers and each pointer is pointing to a particular instance. I'm just confused about pointers and structs.

```
typedef struct book{

        double value1;

        int value2;

} Book;

void function1(Book * dArr){

        dArr->value1 = 200;

        dArr->value2 = 350;

}


int main(){

        Book *array1[10];

        for (i = 0 ; i < SIZE; ++i){

                init2 (array1[i]);

                printf ("In main(): value1: %14d, value2: %6d", array1[i]->value1, array1[i]->value2);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   Book *array1[10];
```

The above declares an array of 10 pointers -- but you haven't set them to point to anything... so when you try to dereference them inside your for-loop, you invoke undefined behavior and your program crashes.

The easiest way to fix the problem is to declare an array of 10 objects, instead, so that there is no concern about uninitialized pointers:

```
   Book array1[10];

   for (i = 0 ; i < SIZE; ++i){

           init2 (&array1[i]);

           printf ("In main(): value1: %14f, value2: %6d\n", array1[i].value1, array1[i].value2);

   }
```

The other approach would be to set the pointers to point to valid objects before trying to deference them (e.g. using the `new` operator, or declaring a separate array of `Book` objects and setting the pointers in the pointer-array to point to the objects in the objects-array)... but that's overkill for what you're trying to do, and introduces unnecessary complications, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: `value1` is a `double` so the `printf` format string should be: "... value1: %14f, ..." (adding a \n on the end would also make it a lot nicer).

Answer (score 1):

as Jeremy noted you are trying to access memory that is not there. I am assuming that you are trying to learn so i spelt out the details. Also i am assuming that your call to init2 in main is a call to function1.

```
int main(){
        int i;
        Book * array1[10];/*create 10 pointer variables to Book. At this stage
                            they point to nothing that is why you get an error
                             when you try to dereference them */
        for(i=0;i<10;++i){
```

/* C-style allocation. Now array1[i] points to the created Book */

```
                array1[i]=(Book *)malloc(sizeof(Book));

               // array1[i]=new Book;//C++ style allocation
                function1(array1[i]);
                printf("In main(): value1: %14f,value2: %6d\n",array1[i]->value1,array1[i]->value2);
        }
```

}